# Fraudulent cheque that cleared

Tags: check, fraud, scams

So I sold a piece of audio equipment to a man overseas who wanted to pay by cheque. I told him that was fine but I would not be shipping it until it had cleared, and he agreed.

A printed cheque finally arrived with a local branch of "Lockerbie" printed on it.

Immediately the man asked me to send the extra part of the cheque funds to a woman who was making collections for him to deliver it. At first I was a little confused but went a long with it, however luckily I never sent the funds as he suddenly went quiet.

Well over a month later now and my local bank has contacted me to say they need to retrieve the cash as it was a fraudulent cheque. I'm personally stuck because I needed those funds to pay off bills and deposits elsewhere (hence why I was having to sell the equipment).

Now the bank initially explained that the funds may take up to 28 days to clear and appear in my account, and as it appeared in my available balance just a little over 26 hours later I phoned the bank to check that the funds were definitely in my account and he could not back track if I sent the parcel out to him.

Where do I stand with this? I have a meeting on Saturday this weekend to go in and talk about it with them at my home branch. Personally I feel like this is their responsibility seen as they had to manually process the cheque themselves and contact the other parties bank account before depositing the funds into my account. Not only that but nearly a month later and they're only just getting in touch?

Comment: You can pretty much count the money, and the equipment as gone.  This is a classic "craiglist-nigerian prince" scam.  Sorry you were a victim, but you will need to make other arrangements to pay your existing bills and cover the money sent to the third party.

Comment: _Immediately the man asked me to send the extra part of the cheque funds to a woman_ that's a Big Red Flag.

Comment: Nothing in your question explicitly indicates when you shipped the audio equipment.

Comment: Anyone who sends you extra money and asks you to send it somewhere else is scamming you. Full stop. It's good you didn't send the extra money off, but that doesn't make the fraudulent money yours.

Comment: So just to clear a few things up (maybe I wasn't in the right mindset yesterday after hearing all this news when typing this out). From what I can tell the bank paid me the money in belief the cheque was fine and they would collect the money from there, they also admitted that they made that decision after manually processing and inspecting the cheque. I understand on that case that the money obviously isn't mine but at the same time I truly believe they are in some blame for not noticing any of the signs before hand. Also the parcel was never shipped as I couldn't get an official address

Comment: out of the tw*t that has screwed me over like this. The frustrating side to all of this is that the bank needs evidence now to prove that I am not at fault and to unblock my account and drop the allegations to the police. They're also talking about surcharges of around £250 on top of the original returned money. Hopefully I can make light to this situation tomorrow at my appointment, maybe even lodge a complaint with the actions they've taken so far.

Comment: @JamesLawson I doubt the bank will need to accept any responsibility for this. Banks make some portion of funds available from cashing a check on a preliminary basis, as a courtesy to the customer. Checks can take a very long time to actually 'clear', particularly if the two banks don't have a prior relationship. This is a known flaw in the banking system that scammers like to exploit. The only alternative for a bank would be to not give you any access to cashed checks for a month or more after depositing.

Comment: Presumably you can still sell the equipment, as you never mailed it to the scammer. Since the transaction failed, you have no valid claim to the cheque funds (whether or not it was fraudulently written). The discussion re: fees/fines for attempting to cash a bad cheque is between you and the bank. It's not really their fault if it turns out the cheque isn't backed by anything. Your question indicates that you "called the bank to check" but not whether they confirmed your assumption that the funds had cleared.

Comment: I'm not really sure where your problem is here - since you didn't send the equipment, you're not out of pocket so it shouldn't really matter who's "at fault" since it's just a sale that fell through. It's not like if the bank had been more careful you'd have the money...  (unless you end up having to pay that £250 surcharge - not sure what that's for but your question wasn't about that). And what are the allegations to the police?

Comment: So the follow up to this was the bank locked all of my accounts (including the ones they didn't pay the cheque into). I went into my local branch, did an interview and they understood what had happened. They promised to unlock my accounts and did after two working days.. however a week later my debit card became unusable again and after a week of battling with the bank they finally admitted fault, they initially claimed they couldn't see any blocks until a senior fraud manager stepped in. In compensation the bank paid out £480 to cover loss of earnings, car fuel costs and the stress incurred.

Answer (score 3):

> Where do I stand with this?

The money was not your's. So co-operate with the bank to get this sent back ASAP.

It is good that the equipment is still with you.

Yes Bank would need evidence that you were a victim and not party to this crime. Co-operate with the relevant authorities and get this resolved.

It is a lesson learnt where luckily no money was lost, but quite a bit of hassle and personal time lost.